# How to prevent external website from being downloaded in wget?

Tags: wget

I'm using wget to download useful website recursively:

```
wget -k -m -r -q -t 1 http://www.web.com/
```

But external website also downloaded along with the website I want.

How to prevent this external website from being downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

Try `-D` or `--domains`, it is a list of domains that will be followed.